# Enterprise Architect: Hide Foreign Key Labels in Database Diagram?

Tags: database, enterprise-architect, database-diagramming

I am using Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect 7 Professional and I can not find a way to hide the labels from Foreign Keys Associations in Database Diagrams.

Yes, I know I can right-click each of the connectors and use the "Set Visibility" option from the context menu but I guess there must be a per-diagram or golabal setting to do it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I do not why I did not see the option previously. Today it just jumped on me.

The answer on how to hide all labels from a diagram is right-click on the diagram, select Properties... Connectors Tab... Check the option "Suppress All Connector Labels".

I am using Sparx System's Enterprise Architect v 7.0.

Comment: To hide the busy footer in each table showing the names of foreign keys and primary keys, see here https://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,48328.0.html